# Mismatch types uint32 and bool in Go

Tags: go

I have a C macro defined like this:

```
#define normalize(c, a) c = (a) + ((a) == 0xFFFFFFFF)
```

I was rewriting it in Go, and as long as I know there is no such things as C macros in Go. Therefore, I created a normal function:

```
func normalize(a uint32, c *uint32) {
    *c = a + (a == 0xFFFFFFFF)
}
```

The problem is that this gives me a type mismatch error. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: you are getting a type error because you are trying to take an an expression that evaluates to a `bool` (a == 0xFFFFFFFF) and add it to a value of type `unit32`. I do not use C frequently, so pardon a potentially naive question - but why are you trying to add a boolean to an unsigned integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your C `normalize` macro assigns `c` to `a` if `a` is not equal to `0xffffffff`, or to `0` otherwise. I'm not sure what kind of normalization it is, but it's not my concern now.

So given the Go function signature you provided, this would work:

```
func normalize(a uint32, c *uint32) {
    if a != 0xffffffff {
        *c = a
    } else {
        *c = 0
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure why not just return a value instead of writing it via `c` pointer?

```
func normalize(a uint32) {
    if a != 0xffffffff {
        return a
    }
    return 0
}
```

Side note: the same applies to your C macro. By the way, the macro evaluates `a` twice, this might come as a surprise if you ever pass some function with side effects as `a`. Any reason not to use (inline) function instead of a macro, or at least make it so that it evaluates to a new value, instead of assigning `c` to it?

Comment: Thank you. It's not my code actually, but they have a few macros that do similar things. Another one being `#define modsub(c, a, b) c = (a - b) - (b > a)`.

Comment: @typos In C that's legal because there is no true boolean. Comparison returns the integers 1 or 0. Go has a true boolean type and will not cast it to integer, so that isn't going to work. `if b > a { c-- }` will work... buuut avoid a rote translation. Modifying a variable inside a macro, or a pointer inside a function, makes the code *very* hard to understand. That macro would be better written as `#define modsub(a, b) (a - b) - (b > a)` and used as `c = modsub(x, y)`. The Go functions should also return their value rather than assign the result to a pointer. Finally, Go will inline functions.